# Make SumatraPDF open advanced settings in Sublime Text

Tags: visual-studio-code, sublime-text, sumatra-pdf

SumatraPDF used to open the advanced settings in Sublime Text, but now all of a sudden it fires up Visual Studio Code (which albeit a fine editor is not the one I regularly use). How do I change it back?

(I have also posted [a question over on Github](https://github.com/sumatrapdfreader/sumatrapdf/discussions/3610).)

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://www.sumatrapdfreader.org/docs/Customize-external-viewers), to change external editor, you can:

- open `Settings` -> `Advanced Settings`
- find `ExternalViewers` section and change it to something like:

```
ExternalViewers [
    [
        CommandLine = subl "$1"
        Name = Sublime Text
    ]
]
```

assuming you have `subl` in `%PATH%`, if not then you can switch that to full path.

You could also then add another block that opens `.pdf`s and other file by default if you just want to affect settings.

---

If that doesn't satisfy you, you could also attempt to change Notepad, which older apps tend to open by default, to another app. Bunch of resources for that all over internet, here's [an example for Windows 11](https://superuser.com/questions/1682483/is-there-any-straightforward-way-to-replace-notepad-exe-in-windows-11).